# Greeting Elijah during coronavirus

Tags: halacha, passover, passover-seder-hagada, eliyahu-hanavi

We are nearing Pesach and the Passover Seder. A time when Jews open the door for Elijah. Many Jews interpret Malachi 3:23, “Behold, I will send you Elijah the prophet before the coming of the great and terrible day of the Lord,” to mean that Elijah will announce the appearance of the messiah.

With the government in lockdown, should we be opening doors? What does the halacha say?

Sources, please.

---

This question was inspired by street minyans (since Jews in Israel need to follow the rules and government regulations of social distancing).

Comment: https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/949656/rabbi-aryeh-lebowitz/opening-the-door-and-pouring-the-kos-for-eliyahu-demonstrations-of-emunah/

Comment: What exactly is your issue? Social distancing? That Elijah will be within a six-foot radius of you?

Comment: Note that your assumption that we open the door at the seder for Eliyahu is of recent origin

Comment: I don't think anyone thinks opening a door is dangerous, not that governments will object

Answer (score 2):

[Opening the Door and Pouring the Kos for Eliyahu - Demonstrations of Emunah](https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/949656/rabbi-aryeh-lebowitz/opening-the-door-and-pouring-the-kos-for-eliyahu-demonstrations-of-emunah/) says at minute 9:20 that we open the door to show that we have absolute faith that it is a ליל שימורים, a night of protection. This is a matter of ruchnius rather than explicit physical protection. This ליל שימורים prevents the mazikim (spiritual enemies) from causing harm. One example is the four cups as normally an even number of cups allows the *mazikim* to cause harm. One of the answers is that this night we do not have to worry about this. We open the door as an overt display of emunah. Noone can do anything to us without the Will of Hashem as happened on the night of Yetzias Mitzraim. (minute 18:25)

On a physical basis, even during the current circumstance someone is able to open the door to accept a package being delivered. Since there is no physical person at your door to come in, there is no danger that you are submitting yourself to. Similarly pouring the kos of Eliyahu involves showing that we are not afraid of the *mazikim*.

At minute 22 he gives a second reason which also explains why people open the door. Hashem has decreed the night of the seder to be the night of geulah. As a result we open the door to see that Eliyahu Hanavi is coming to announce the coming of the Mashiach. Thus we are not opening the door to show that we are not afraid of someone coming in, but that if Eliyahu comes now we are ready and indeed, once the mashiach comes there will be no fear.

As a result, we open the door, say the pesukim of שפוך חמתך and then after the malach (of whom we should have no fear) leaves, close the door.

At minute 31 he says that the kos would therefore be in case he comes to the seder, we will have a kos available for him to drink. This is showing our extreme emunah.

He points out that normally we can eat chadash on the second day of Pesach. However we wait for the end of the day in case Eliyahu Hanavi comes and we get to bring the korban omer.